# Element [servlet] is not a valid root element

Tags: xml, web, web.xml

This is the log of the error, can some body please help me what might be worng?

```
In-place deployment at E:\Pavan\Java Web Apps\WebApplication2\build\web
Initializing...
deploy?DEFAULT=E:\Pavan\Java Web Apps\WebApplication2\build\web&name=WebApplication2&contextroot=/WebApplication2&force=true failed on GlassFish Server 3+ 
 Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app [WebApplication2] : Deployment descriptor file WEB-INF/web.xml in archive [web]. Element [servlet] is not a valid root element. Please see server.log for more details.
E:\Pavan\Java Web Apps\WebApplication2\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1022: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
```

This is my `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>
Example
</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>Exmple Servlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Example</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/Example/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
 version="3.0">
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
</web-app>
```

My main aim was to create a simple file to accept userid and password and then display it on another page.

Answer (score 2):

The elements in your `web.xml` are in the wrong order. You seem to have inserted the `<servlet>` element at the top instead of inside the `<web-app>` element.

It needs to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
 version="3.0">
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>
Example
</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>Exmple Servlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Example</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/Example/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Also, I'm pretty sure, you servlet class name is not `Exmple Servlet`. :-) The application will still throw an error, if you try to start it like this.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `<webapp>` at the start.